# Real Time Append to Image

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, real-time, data-visualization

I need to capture audio data from the computer mic, process it and then plot it in real time. Processing each frame will produce a 1-D array which I want to display in an image where each value in the array is mapped to a color. The next audio frame is processed similarly and is then displayed on the next row of the image and so on. In matlab, one can achieve this using imagesc function. I also want the user to be able to scroll up and down to see current or previous data. 
I believe I will need to buffer the processed data in a file or database and then asynchronously update the plot as mentioned above.
I'm trying to achieve all the above using C#.

My question is: what is the best way to generate the image/plot? I've done a lot of research (Microsoft Chart, VTK, several codeproject articles..) but couldn't find exactly what I want.

Also, what would be the best database to use in such case?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a component that does exactly the things you've described. In most frameworks/bundles all the images get visualized by native system calls (in the end) which accept strides, buffers and so on, driving all by HANDLE. So, either you generate next time new image with new rows or just draw it yourself by stacking prev image to new one.

Scrolling (AKA windowing) is not trivial but possible again with already pre-created image in memory which is fixed. However, please note, that GDI+ based images (.NET Bitmap) is kind of limited for more than 9000px size. Please consider using alternative like IPP, AForge images.

I recommend you draw rows yourself because in your task re-sizing in going to be an issue because of rows bluring.
So, all in all, you might need to do it yourself.